# SHA256 hashed password validation in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, hash, passwords, sha256

I'm trying to convert a c# program into javascript. 
The purpose is to validate a clear text password against its sha-256 hash stored in a database. This code will be executed server-side.

The c# program was implemented following this MSDN's article [How to Hash Passwords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602%28v=cs.70%29.aspx).

In order to validate my implementation, I was given an example hash for the password "test" with a randomly generated 4 characters long salt .

Here is what I wrote so far :

```
var unhashedPass = "test";
var originalHashedPass = "F27B595D3CBBC60ACEAC68E4DA6A2629558FEC383E0B81F764E443C68B0E9808096CDF2D";

var saltStringLength = 4;
var unicodeCharLength = 2;
var saltHexLength = unicodeCharLength * saltStringLength;
var saltHex = originalHashedPass.substr(0, saltHexLength);

var strSalt1 = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(saltHex.substr(0, 2), 16).toFixed());
var strSalt2 = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(saltHex.substr(2, 2), 16).toFixed());
var strSalt3 = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(saltHex.substr(4, 2), 16).toFixed());
var strSalt4 = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(saltHex.substr(6, 2), 16).toFixed());

//var strSalt = str2rstr_utf16le(strSalt1 + strSalt2 + strSalt3 + strSalt4);
var strSalt = strSalt1 + strSalt2 + strSalt3 + strSalt4;

var finalHash = saltHex + hex_sha256(strSalt + unhashedPass).toUpperCase();

return (finalHash == originalHashedPass);
```

This code is one of multiple variants I tried, attempting to transform the hexadecimal salt in a valid string (see commented line for example). None seemed to work.

hex_sha256 and str2rstr_utf16le functions come from [this javascript SHA implementation](http://anmar.eu.org/projects/jssha2/)

I assume the c# part I fail to correctly "translate" in javascript is the conversion of the salt into a string.

```
binarySaltValue[0] = byte.Parse(saltValue.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
binarySaltValue[1] = byte.Parse(saltValue.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
binarySaltValue[2] = byte.Parse(saltValue.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
binarySaltValue[3] = byte.Parse(saltValue.Substring(6, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

I noticed that the c# implementation uses array of bytes but I guess I have to use strings in javascript.

I also wonder if my issue has something to do with the fact that the c# program is computing Unicode encoded strings.

Do you have any suggestion ?

---

**EDIT**

To clarify my problem : I can't manage to validate in javascript the password "test" against it's SHA256 salted hash "F27B595D3CBBC60ACEAC68E4DA6A2629558FEC383E0B81F764E443C68B0E9808096CDF2D" (calculated earlier in a c# program).

Comment: Think about what you are proposing for a second. By doing it in Javascript, anybody can push javascript into the page like, `alert(unhashedPass)` and compromise the security of your application.  You will be prone to MITM attacks as well as other javascript injection attacks.

Comment: `var unhashedPass : String` is not valid JavaScript. You can't declare explicit variable types.

Comment: That will be server-side executed javascript so security won't be an issue.

Comment: What is the data you're hashing in the end? Is it correct that it are the bytes `f2 7b 59 5d 74 65 73 74` (the four salt bytes, plus `"test"`)? It hashes to something else than you have in `originalHashedPass` (also without the prepended salt in this variable).

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you. The string I'm trying to hash, when  salted, looks more like this : "ò{Y]test". I'm not hashing a string containing hexadecimal values (or should I ?).

Comment: @Benjamin Delichère: That string is what I meant. But that string hashes to something different than to what you're checking equality against if I'm not mistaking (http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?hex=F27B595D74657374).

Answer (score 2):

Since you're saying this is server side, I'm guessing Node, in which case:

https://github.com/brainfucker/hashlib

If it's something other than node:

https://github.com/h2non/jsHashes

but that will be slower than the first one since it's a pure JS implementation (the first is in C exposed to JS)

Comment: It is not Node.js but thanks anyway. I'm going to test jsHashes right now (although it seems quite similar to jsSHA2 ... I suspect that my problem comes from the way I translate the hex-encoded salt rather than the hash function itself).